# Launcher stuck in "offline mode"?

Tags: eve-online

I'm trying to log into EVE Online but whenever I start the launcher it is stating that I'm currently offline and that no connection could be made to the server;

[image]

I can see from looking at EVE Mon that Tranquillity is online and I'm obviously connected to the internet.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

How can I play EVE Online when I can't get past the launcher?

Comment: I had this issue yesterday, submitted a petition, and it cleared up  20 minutes later without them doing anything. I would submit a petition and see if it clears up on its own.

Comment: Since this was asked 2 days ago: I think your problem is connected with the DOS attack against the Tranquillity server cluster, which lead to a prolonged downtime (source: http://kotaku.com/eve-online-says-it-has-taken-down-its-tranquility-serve-510934470). According to EVE's twitter, it should work again.

Comment: No it's not - it predates the ddos by a day and is still occurring right now, the ddos didn't start on Saturday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: One of the recent patches has resolved this launcher issue.

---

I tried a variety of things to resolve the problem, none of which worked, and in lieu of a response from CCP I ultimately decided to reinstall the game from scratch into a new folder. Upon reinstalling the game, the launcher went through and applied the new update to bring up the new launcher and then worked immediately.

I am still waiting for a response from CCP as to how they'd recommend fixing this problem and still have my old game client installed so I can test their response, but for the time being it appears the solution to the problem is to reinstall the game.

Comment: I have it in offline mode too. I have a fresh install on Linux, launching using Wine 1.6

Comment: You could also only reinstall the launcher, already worked twice for me. This helpdesk article from CCP support explain how to do it : https://ccpcommunity.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202664365-Reinstalling-the-Launcher

Answer (score 4):

You can go around the launcher and just execute the exefile.exe in the bin subdirectory of eve.

I dont know how to get the launcher back in normal mode though.

Comment: The developers have stated that at some point in the future they're going to remove the ability to do this, it works for now though (well, not this very second since EVE is currently offline, but...)

Comment: I didn't think it would but this solved the problem! Running the exefile.exe triggered the update of the launcher, which ran correctly afterwards!